# JQuery plugin lightbox_me in rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, lightbox

Cheers! I am trying to implement popup window with Lightbox_me plugin in my Ruby On Rails application. I have downloaded `jquery.lightbox_me.js`, put it to `app/assets/javascripts`, 
add `//= require jquery.lightbox_me` in `application.js` file, and in `home.js.coffee` (I've HomeController) I do stuff like this:

```
`$(".popup-button").click (e) ->
  alert "!!!"
  $(".download_layout").lightbox_me centered: true
  e.preventDefault()
```

alert shows normally, but .lightbox_me doesn't work. Whats the problem?

**EDIT:**
application.js

```
//.......
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.lightbox_me
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Could you post your `application.js`?

Comment: Just suggesting : why don't you use ID of the DOM element in your `coffee` ? Like :`$("#download_layout").lightbox_me ...` . I think classes are for CSS , id's for javascript. I can see your button works with a class reference , but ... Do you have `//= require_self` on top of the manifest file ?

Comment: added `//= require_self` and change classes of DOM elements to id's. Still not working, I am stacked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to stick to the CoffeeScript syntax :

```
$(document).ready ->
  $(".popup-button").click (e) ->
    $("#download_layout").lightbox_me 
      centered: true
    e.preventDefault()
```

EDIT : Don't forget to place this very important string on the top of your `.js.coffee`(I have replicated your code on my machine and it works) :

```
$(document).ready ->
```

Comment: We'll not give up :) Can you post your view with the popup-button?

Comment: simple test view with `%button.popup-putton +` and `.download_layout
  "some text here"` with `display: none` style.

Comment: If you've changed your coffee to use id's , it should be `#download_layout` . Also , insert in your `application.js` `//= require jquery.ui` .

Comment: it was changed, exactly, I've just turned it back.
Added `//= require jquery.ui` and now I have:
`couldn't find file 'jquery.ui'`

Comment: It's really `jquery-ui` , I beg you pardon .

Comment: Still not working though, could you paste here application.js, js.coffee file and view, that you've replicated?

Comment: Do you still need to post my solution on  a gist ?